# Why does `ReadFile()` return error 87?

Tags: java, winapi, jna

Below is the Java code.

```
HANDLE h = kernel32.CreateFile("\\\\.\\d:",
                               kernel32.GENERIC_READ 
                               | kernel32.GENERIC_WRITE, 
                               0, null, kernel32.OPEN_EXISTING,
                               0, null);

IntByReference nbread = new IntByReference();   

ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(48);

boolean result = kernel32.ReadFile(h, b, b.capacity(), nbread, null);

System.out.println(kernel32.GetLastError());
```

it gives the error `87 (Invalid parameter)`

What might be the problem ?

Comment: which line is line 87?

Comment: Most likely the invalid parameter is the first one.  If you're trying to open the root directory of the `D:` drive, use `"D:/"` instead, and check the error code after _that_ call as well.  You should also ensure that 48 bytes is enough to read the contents of whatever file it is you're reading.

Comment: It's invalid to call `GetLastError()` unless you actually got an error, and there is no evidence here that you did.

Comment: @technomage: `"\\\\.\\d:"` is a perfectly valid path string for `CreateFile()`: "*When opening a volume or removable media drive (for example, a floppy disk drive or flash memory thumb drive), the lpFileName string should be the following form: **"\\.\X:"**. Do not use a trailing backslash (\), which indicates the root directory of a drive.*"  What is more likely happening is that `CreateFile()` is failing and an invalid `HANDLE` is being passed to `ReadFile()`.  Assuming `ReadFile()` is even failing in the first place (per EJP's comment), as there is no error checking in this code.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't checking for errors. You must put that right. The documentation explains how. There's no substitute for reading the documentation.

Check the return values. Compare `h` against `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. That value indicates failure, and if so, and only is so, call `GetLastError`.

The documentation says this about opening volumes for direct access:

> The following requirements must be met for such a call to succeed:
>
> - The caller must have administrative privileges. For more information, see Running with Special Privileges.
> - The dwCreationDisposition parameter must have the OPEN_EXISTING flag.
> - When opening a volume or floppy disk, the dwShareMode parameter must have the FILE_SHARE_WRITE flag.

You aren't meeting the final requirement. And possibly not the first.

As for the call to `ReadFile` you aren't checking the return value. The documentation says:

> **Return value**
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero (TRUE).
>
> If the function fails, or is completing asynchronously, the return value is zero (FALSE). To get extended error information, call the GetLastError function.

You will also need to make sure you perform sector aligned reads. You are not doing so.

Your calls to `GetLastError` are wrong too. They need to be fixed. See this question: [How to make GetLastError reliably work with JNA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413963/how-to-make-getlasterror-reliably-work-with-jna)